# installed the course rating on Moodle 3.10. However, attempting to rate the course, getting error "No define call for core_form/modalform

Tags: moodle

I am installing a course rating plugin in moodle version 3.10.7. and this course rating plugin version  compatible with moodle 3.11 version.However, when attempting to rate the course, I encountered an error stating

> No define call for core_form/modalform.

It gives error from amd/build/requires.min.js file

I tried it to make compatible with moodle 3.10.7 version. I want moodle course rating plugin which compatible with moodle 3.10.7 version

Answer (score 0):

Modal forms was added to Moodle 3.11 for MDL-64554

https://moodledev.io/general/releases/3.11

See

```
git log lib/form/amd/src/modalform.js
```

So the Course Rating plugin isn't compatible with Moodle 3.10

https://moodle.org/plugins/tool_courserating/versions

I couldn't see a rating plugin for Moodle 3.10

https://moodle.org/plugins/?q=rating%20moodle-version:3.10%20sort-by:downloads

If you are unable to upgrade to a later version of Moodle, then you will probably need to develop your own course rating plugin

Comment: Thanks, Russell, please help me to develop my rating plugin compatible with Moodle 3.10

Comment: or If I added the moodle form inside lib/form/amd/src/modalform.js in moodle 3.10 version, then it gives me an error SetBodyContent

Comment: Thank you so much, I have created the same files in 3.10 and it works